# Akka Streams KillSwitch in alpakka jms

Tags: scala, akka-stream, alpakka

I have a scenario in which I am starting multiple jmsSource (for different queues) using alpakka. I also need to detach the queues at any point in time. So I have added KillSwitch to the jms akka streams as below :-

```
trait MessageListener  {

  lazy val jmsPipeline = jmsSource
    .map { x => log.info(s"Received message ${x} from ${queue}"); x }
    .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(Sink.foreach { x => pipelineActorRef ! PreProcessorMessage(x) })
    (Keep.both)
    .run()

   def start(): Unit = {
             log.info("Invoking listener : {}", queue)
             jmsPipeline
             log.info("listener : {} started", queue)
          }
  def stop():Unit  =     jmsPipeline._1.shutdown()

  def queue: String

}

object ListenerA extends MessageListener {
  override def queue: String = "Queue_A"
}

object ListenerB extends MessageListener {
  override def queue: String = "Queue_B"
}
```

.. and so on.

After I start up the application, all the queues are connected and works fine. But when I try to detach the queue using the stop method, not all the queues gets disconnected and the behaviour is random. I also checked that the killSwitch is different for all the listeners.

Could someone please tell me what's getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your logs are supporting the illusion that you're connected to multiple queues with distinct streams, but you have multiple streams that are probably connected to the same queue. In both of your listener objects, the logger records the overridden `queue` name, but this queue name is not used to configure `jmsSource`.

You don't show the definition of `jmsSource`; apparently it's defined somewhere outside of the `MessageListener` trait, in which case both `ListenerA` and `ListenerB` are using the same `jmsSource`. In other words, while `ListenerA` and `ListenerB` have distinct instances of `jmsPipeline` (which is why the kill switches are different), both of these `jmsPipeline` instances are derived from the same `jmsSource` instance (unless `jmsSource` is a `def` that creates a different `Source` on each invocation, but even if this were the case, the basic problem remains: `queue` is not used in the configuration).

In Alpakka, the JMS queue is configured on `JmsSourceSettings`, so `jmsSource` probably looks something like the following:

```
val jmsSource: Source[String, NotUsed] = JmsSource.textSource(
  JmsSourceSettings(connectionFactory).withBufferSize(10).withQueue("MyQueue")
)                        // the queue is configured here ^
```

When `ListenerA.start()`, for example, is called, the following is logged:

```
Invoking listener : Queue_A
listener : Queue_A started
```

Again, `"Queue_A"` in the above log statements is the value of the overridden `def queue: String` member in `ListenerA`; it's not necessarily the queue that is actually configured in `jmsSource` (`"MyQueue"` in the above example). The same thing with `ListenerB` and with the messages that you're logging in the `map` combinator.

A straightforward fix is to move the definition of `jmsSource` and its `JmsSourceSettings` inside the `MessageListener` trait and actually use `queue` in those settings.